# Jmeter proxy server doesn't capture file upload request

Tags: file-upload, jmeter

I was trying to capture a file upload request from the Jmeter's proxy server but while uploading the file error message was displayed. I had already configured the `proxy.binary.types` property to `application/x-amf,application/x-java-serialized-object,application/octet-stream,application/vnd.ms-excel`.

Below is the error message displayed on UI:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: employee_template.xls (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.PostWriter.writeFileToStream(PostWriter.java:406)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.PostWriter.sendPostData(PostWriter.java:115)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampler.sendPostData(HTTPSampler.java:122)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampler.sample(HTTPSampler.java:508)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:965)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:242)
```

Answer (score 5):

Copy the files to upload in bin folder of JMeter, see:

- http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/File-Upload-failure-td530225.html