# Unable to record Upload Panel using JMeter

Tags: upload, jmeter, seam

I have an upload panel in my seam application and I want to record this using Jmeter.
But this tool does not allow to upload the file whereas manually I can do that.

So any suggestion on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Put the file in jmeter/bin folder and it should work.
You can use firefox for recording.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to search first through jmeter-tagged questions?
Asked many times before.

Look into these:

- [JMeter - File upload and file download scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8793096/993246)
- [Jmeter Upload Error in Recording](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12367453/993246)